# is Flying Saucer project closed?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

Someone know what happened with Flying Saucer project?

http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ site down and I can't get access to manuals :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project has been moved to https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Comment: cool, but new site havn't contains manuals :( You can get access to old site as described in update to ny question.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sorry I didn't see this question when it was first posted, and that the original poster didn't contact us on our mailing lists - though that may have been due to the project hosting problems at the time.

For the record - as a committer to the project: the Flying Saucer downloads/artifacts, our documentation, and our issue tracker, are now hosted on

http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

as we decided to move away from java.net as a hosting provider. Unfortunately as the project was hosted on java.net for many years there are many links to our old host.

java.net itself went through a major move to new infrastructure in the last 6 months and this caused some projects to be unavailable for a short time, including ours. I recently updated the java.net project page to point to our new project home. All issues in the java.net issue tracker were also moved to Google Code.

We host our code on GitHub: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

We reached a sort of plateau with our last release (R8), as the code is production-ready (and used at a number of companies), implements CSS 2.1 well (we think), and is reasonably bug-free. Since our last release there has only been a slow trickle of bug fixes in trunk. We will release in the near future, although feature-wise, this will be more like R8.1 as opposed to R9.

The current core contributors are not actively developing new features or large-scale changes, however, we welcome contributors and do occasionally receive patches from our users. This has become easier for us to manage since our move to Git.

We look forward to hearing from you on our mailing lists, linked from our project home page.

-- Patrick Wright, contributor to FS since the project's inception

Comment: thx, for your replay. have you plans by providing access to flying-saucer via maven?

Comment: java.net still has a broken SSL certificate - my FF (its the latest release) complains :(

Comment: A typo from when I first posted that comment - our current release is R8, not R9. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the Flying Saucer project now have moved to Github.

Check it out: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/

Answer (score 2):

Note that the github version have gone up [past the R8 now (currently reads 9.0.4)](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/releases), and you find that on [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-core).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the project is essentially dead. I believe that the last release was in April of 2009 some time.

Comment: That is not the same as the site / project going away for ever.

Comment: Sorry this is true. That being said, the project page may have been left for a long enough period of time that it has been removed. xhtmlrenderer still appears in the project search feature. 

Time will tell I guess.... Wait it out unless anyone else knows definitively.

Comment: Also, the search shows recent emails on the mailing list ... though of course you cannot see them at the moment.